# Stone-Weierstrass theorem for holomorphic functions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

The [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) has an analog for the algebras of smooth functions, called

> **Naсhbin's theorem**: An involutive subalgebra $A$ in the algebra ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ of smooth functions on a smooth manifold $M$ is dense in ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ if and only if $A$ separates the points and the tangent vectors of $M$.

See details in: "L.Nachbin. Sur les algèbres denses de fonctions diffèrentiables sur une variètè, C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris 228 (1949) 1549-1551", or in  [J.G.Llavona's monograph](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Approximation_of_Continuously_Differenti.html?id=C7auJPRK5nAC&redir_esc=y), or [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2424).

This is strange, I can't find an analog for the algebras of holomorphic functions (on complex manifolds). Did anybody think about this?

> **Question**: let $A$ be a subalgebra in the algebra ${\mathcal O}(M)$ of holomorphic functions on a complex manifold $M$ (as a first approximation, we can think that $M$ is just an open subset in ${\mathbb C}^n$). Which conditions should $A$ satisfy for being dense in ${\mathcal O}(M)$?

---

**Remark.** By topology on ${\mathcal O}(M)$ I mean the usual topology of uniform convergence on compact sets in $M$. The algebra ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ is also endowed with its usual topology, which can be described, for example, as follows.

1. For each function $f\in {\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ let us define its *support* as the closure of the set of the points where $f$ does not vanish:
   $$
   \text{supp}f=\overline{\{x\in M:\ f(x)\ne 0\}}.
   $$
   An equivalent definition: $\text{supp}f$ is the set of the points in $M$ where $f$ has non-zero [germs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)):
   $$
   \text{supp}f=\{x\in M:\ f\not\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ x)\}.
   $$
2. Let us define *differential operators* (see e.g. [S.Helgason's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821826735)) on $M$ as linear mappings $D:{\mathcal C}^\infty(M)\to {\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ which do not extend the support of functions:
   $$
   \text{supp}Df\subseteq \text{supp}f,\quad f\in{\mathcal C}^\infty(M).
   $$
   Equivalently, $D$ is *local*, i.e. the value of $Df$ in a point $x\in M$ depends only on the germ of $f$ in $x$: 
   $$
   \forall f,g\in{\mathcal C}^\infty(M)\quad \forall x\in M\qquad f\equiv g\ (\text{mod}\ x)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad Df(x)=Dg(x).
   $$
3. Then we say that a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to a function $f$ in ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$
   $$
   f_n\overset{{\mathcal C}^\infty(M)}{\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}}f
   $$
   if and only if for each differential operator $D:{\mathcal C}^\infty(M)\to {\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ the sequence of functions $Df_n$ converges to $Df$ in the space ${\mathcal C}(M)$ of continuous functions with the usual *topology of uniform convergence on compact sets* in $M$:
   $$
   Df_n\overset{{\mathcal C}(M)}{\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}}Df
   $$

Of course, this is equivalent to the convergence in ${\mathcal C}^\infty(U)$  for each smooth local chart $\varphi:U\to V$, $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$, $V\subseteq M$. This is also  equivalent to what Alex M. writes about vector fields:
$$
f_n\overset{{\mathcal C}^\infty(M)}{\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}}f
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \forall k\ \forall X_1,...,X_k\in{\mathcal X}(M) \quad
X_1...X_kf_n\overset{{\mathcal C}(M)}{\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}}X_1...X_kf.
$$

Comment: Can you formulate Runge's theorem in general terms of the algebra of rational functions with enough poles (one in each component of the complement)?

Comment: Runge's theorem is about a concrete subalgebra $A$, the algebra of rational functions, but I am asking about an arbitrary subalgebra $A\subseteq{\mathcal O}(M)$. I don't know, maybe there were generalizations...

Comment: If you are looking for an abstract condition it should apply to the concrete situation. I believe it is thus a good idea to try to formulate the concrete situation in general abstract terms.

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe...

Comment: Does someone know how to deal with the case of a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ ? or basically with the unit disc in fact by Riemann's theorem. Because of Runge's theorem this sugest that this is the simplest case and that bounded connected component in the complement will create additional difficulties...

Comment: @SimonHenry, as far as I understand, even in the case of $M={\mathbb C}$ there is no answer.

Comment: Just to check, the topology on $\mathcal{O}(M)$ is uniform convergence on compact subsets of $M$?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe if we look at "algebras" of meromorphic functions instead of holomorphic one can get better result. it seem to remove obstruction related to non simply connected open and the one in David Speyer post. We saw meromorphic functions as functions to $P^1$ so they are topologized and they have a kind of algebraic structure (for example, one can make rational functions in several variable acts on them) that can replace the actual algebra structure. (PS I'm considering the constant equal to infinity as a meromorphic functions to simplify things...)

Comment: Simon, I don't understand you. Why meromorphic functions? You can consider a narrower class, the class of entire functions on ${\mathbb C}$, and even in this situation the problem is unsolved: if $A$ is a subalgebra in ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C})$, nobody knows which conditions $A$ should satisfy for being dense in ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C})$.

Comment: The point to consider meromorphic function is to ask stability under rational fraction, for example stability under inversion, this puts stronger algebraic condition than just "being an algebra" and kill the counterexample given by David speyer and the obvious counterexample you have with non simply connected open of $\mathbb{C}$ (the algebra of functions that extend holomorphically to a given bounded connected component of the complement is closed). And as rational fraction approximation work a lot better than polynomial approximation it provide a real advantage....

Comment: Dear @SergeiAkbarov, could you please be so kind as to edit your question and add the topology on $C^\infty (M)$ under which the theorem is valid? I haven't been able to find Nachbin's original article, and Llavona's monograph is not easy to read in Google Books (plus - it's a typographic and notational mess). In your own book you use stereotype spaces (which are not of interest in my work), but the core of the topology seems to be *"uniform convergence on compact sets with respect to each differential operator"* - what *exactly* does "with respect to each differential operator" mean?

Comment: *(continued)* Is the topology given by $$f_i \to f \iff X_1 \dots X_k f_i \to X_1 \dots X_k f \text{ uniformly on compacts } \forall k \ge 0 \ \forall X_1, \dots, X_k \in \mathcal X (M) ?$$ In the presence of a covariant derivative, would this be equivalent to $$\nabla ^k f_i (X_1, \dots, X_k) \to \nabla ^k f (X_1, \dots, X_k) \text{ uniformly on compacts } \forall k \ge 0 \ \forall X_1, \dots, X_k \in \mathcal X (M) ?$$

Comment: @AlexM. I edited. There is no need to take into account the stereotype theory, when you define topology on ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$. This is equivalent to your condition with vector fields $X_i$.

Comment: One more question please, if I may: in defining this convergence, you use *sequences*, not *nets*. Is it obvious that this topology is first countable?

Comment: Yes, it's obvious, if $M$ is $\sigma$-compact: then ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ is a Fréchet space (I don't know, perhaps people consider now non-$\sigma$-compact manifolds as well). For the case when $M$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^m$ this topology on ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ is described in Rudin's "Functional analysis": http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analysis-Walter-Rudin/dp/0070542368

Comment: Alex, you can contact me directly by e-mail: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=8763&option_lang=eng

Answer (score 8):

$\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}\def\cO{\mathcal{O}}$

Here is a candidate counterexample for $M= \CC$: Is $e^{-z}$ in the closure of the algebra generated by $e^z$ and $e^{\sqrt{2}z}$? My current guess is "no", but I need to move on to actual work.

---

I will show that separating points and separating tangents is not enough for $M = \CC^2$.

Let $A \subset \cO(\CC^2)$ be those holomorphic functions $f$ such that $f(z,z^{-1})$ extends holomorphically to $z=0$. We observe:

**$A$ is a subalgebra:** This is obvious.

**$A$ is closed:** Proof We have $f \in A$ if and only if $\oint f(z,z^{-1}) z^n dz=0$ for all $n \geq 0$, where the integral is on a circle around $0$. This fact is preserved by uniform limits on compact sets. (Specifically, by uniform limits on that circle.)

**$A$ separates points:** Note that the functions $f(x,y) = x$, $g(x,y) = xy$ and $h(x,y) = y (xy-1)$ are all in $A$. The functions $f$ and $g$ alone separate $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ unless $x_1=x_2=0$. In that case, $h$ separates them.

**$A$ separates tangent vectors:** Again, $df$ and $dg$ are linearly independent at all points where $x \neq 0$, and $df$ and $dh$ are linearly independent at $x=0$.

**$A \neq \cO(\CC^2)$** Clearly, $y \not \in A$.

I remembered this counterexample from [an old blog post of mine](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/the-plane-is-not-maximally-affine/).

Note that we could replace $z \mapsto (z, z^{-1})$ with any map $\phi$ from the punctured disc $D^{\ast}$ to $\CC^2$. There are many such $\phi$'s, and they all appear to impose independent conditions. This makes me pessimistic about any simple criterion for equality when $M = \CC^2$.

Comment: David, your example is interesting, but I think, you did not understand my question. First, I have no hypotheses on what the answer should be. Second, separating points does not mean the equality of spectra. For example, from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem it follows that the algebra $A$ of almost periodic functions is dense in ${\mathcal C}({\mathbb R})$, but $\text{Spec}(A)\cong\text{Bohr compactification of} \ {\mathbb R}\ne{\mathbb R}\cong\text{Spec}({\mathcal C}({\mathbb R}))$ (if $\text{Spec}$ is defined somewhat reasonably, say, if it means continuous involutive characters).

Comment: I deleted remarks about Spec since I decided I didn't know what I was talking about. But would you agree that this suggests that there is no simple answer for $M = \mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: David, actually, I would not expect that the criteria for ${\mathcal O}(M)$ and for ${\mathcal C}^\infty(M)$ will be similar. I would suppose that separating points will be their common part, but separating tangent vectors sounds strange for me.

Comment: Separating tangent vectors (meaning that $\{ df \}_{f \in A}$ spans the space of complex linear functionals on the tangent space) is certainly necessary. Note that we can write $f'(0)$ as $\oint f(z) dz/z^2$, so this is a closed condition.

Comment: Necessary, but I would be surprised if it were essential in the answer. I believe, there must be a much more strong condition instead of separating tangent vectors.

Comment: I think @DavidESpeyer's candidate counterexample for $\mathbb C$ does not work and $e^{-z}$ is in the closure of the subalgebra generated by $e^z,e^{\sqrt 2 z}$ - otherwise there is a compactly-supported complex measure $\mu$ such that $f(u):=\int_{\mathbb C} e^{uz} d\mu(z)$ has zeroes at $\mathbb N+\sqrt 2 \mathbb N$ but not at $-1$. But $f$ has order $\leq 1$ and the size of $\left(\mathbb N+\sqrt 2 \mathbb N\right)\cap B(0,r)$ grows quadratically as $r\to\infty$, which contradicts Jensen's formula